# Can't click on links of my footer on mobile version

Tags: html, css, wordpress

For my work I had to create a custom homepage for an existing Wordpress website. Since my boss liked my footer I had to implement my own footer in the theme used.

My footer works fine but in mobile version, I can't click on links...

Here is the website: [website](https://www.ebquad.be)

Does anyone have an idea ?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3  text-left footer-column">
        <h3>EB Quad</h3>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="https://www.ebquad.be/">Accueil</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.ebquad.be/atelier/">Atelier</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.ebquad.be/occasions/">Occasions</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.ebquad.be/contact/">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.ebquad.be/livre-dor/">Livre d'or</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3  text-left footer-column">
        <h3>CF Moto</h3>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="https://www.ebquad.be/quads/">Quads</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.ebquad.be/buggys/">Buggys</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3  text-right footer-column">
        <h3>Randonnées</h3>
        <ul>
            <a href="https://www.ebquad.be/randonnees/">
                <li>Nos randonnées</li>
            </a>
            <li><a href="https://www.ebquad.be/agenda/">Agenda</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.ebquad.be/photos/rando-2018">Photos</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.ebquad.be/tarifs-informations/">Informations/Tarifs</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3  text-right footer-column">
        <h3>Informations</h3>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/E.b.+Renove/@50.3840829,4.0316377,15z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0xe36a2bfccc6eb3da?ved=2ahUKEwj5r93ciZjfAhVQNOwKHfAYCtQQ_BIwDXoECAYQCA" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                    Route de Beaumont 10<br>
                    7041 Givry (Mons)</a></li>
            <li><a href="mailto:info@eri-renove.be">info@eri-renove.be</a></li>
            <li><a href="tel:0495447304">0495/447.304</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- .footer-widget-wrap -->
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center">
        <div style="font-size:12px; margin:auto; text-align:center;">Site réalisé par:</div>
        <a  href="http://www.mds-digitalagency.be" class="watermark-link" target="_blank"><img src="https://www.ebquad.be/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/mds_logo.png"
             style="width: 64px; margin-bottom:30px;" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-bottom-wrap col-md-12">
        EB QUAD © Tous droits réservés | <a href="http://www.ebquad.be/conditions-generales/">Conditions générales</a>

    </div><!-- .footer-bottom-wrap -->




</div><!-- container -->
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include all relevant code in the question. Links should be purely supplementary but not required to visit in order for us to understand your question.

Comment: what version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: Your `.footer-bottom-wrap` element is overlaid on top of the link element containers, preventing clicks from reaching the links.  (As @Utkanos said, though, you should include the relevant code sufficient for reproducing the problem in the question, rather than just linking to your site -- as is, this question will become useless to future users once you fix this bug.)  (You've added the HTML, which is a start, but isn't enough to reproduce the issue; ideally you'd construct a [mcve] demonstrating the problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.footer-bottom-wrap` covers the whole footer. Add `display: inline-block` to this element and all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Since your links are float elements they aren't displayed as the normal flow, and your .foote-bottom-wrap elemnt is not a float element this is why this element will cover all of your links.. you can fix it using this class..

```
.footer-bottom-wrap {
  ...
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

This property fix this behavior.. you can find a good tutorial to understand float behavior [here](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)

Answer (score 0):

Add this css inside your stylesheet

```
.footer-bottom-wrap {float: left;}
```

Comment: It works but has no explanation, and depend on the misuse of `float` which could cause other layout issues later on.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your style.css line number 380 "overflow: hidden;"

[image]

Answer (score -1):

It's caused by your css code just try to add
via HTML

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<!--before-->
<div class="footer-bottom-wrap col-md-12">
```

Or via CSS

```
.footer-bottom-wrap {
    color: #787977;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```